# Can LCD monitor react tolighting of the surrounding enviroment

Tags: windows, display, lcd

I have a new LCD monitor EIZO and I have observed the following surprising thing:
when I turn on the lights in my room, the monitor becomes much brighter than when I
turn them off. Is it true or my eyes are lying to me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many types of display have ambient light sensors so they dim in dark environments and brighten in well-lit ones. There may be settings you can adjust if you don’t like the result. https://www.eizo.com/products/flexscan/ecoview_microsite/auto_ecoview/